# do we have a java queue object or mechanism to handle batch treatment?

Tags: java, queue

Does Java support any queue object or mechanism to handle batch treatment?

ex: we have a queue(or any desired queue object), some producer push item into the queue one by one, my target is when we have 10 items or more than 10 items in this queue, we can trigger some handler to treat it in one batch.

or it is not triggered automatically, we need to find a way to loop the queue gracefully at the handler side.

do we have typical and high performance object or lib to handle this?

thanks, 
Emre

Answer (score 2):

Batch processing in Queue could be achievable with wait/notify, something like you would block thread call against the resource upto it is available or not.

```
public class MyQueue implements Queue<Object>{
        public synchronized List<Object> peek() {
        if(this.list.size()>=10)
                  this.list.wait();
        return Collections.subList(0,10);
    }
        @Override
    public boolean add(Object e) {
        this.list.add(e);
                if(this.list.size()>=10)
                  this.list.notifyAll(); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

*it is not triggered automatically*

In that case you can call wait with specified time out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BlockingQueue.drainTo()` to automatically obtain batches of tasks to be performed.  This is suitable to over 100K task per second.

If you need higher performance queuing you can use the more complex [Disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.com/disruptor/) or [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) which can queue into the millions of tasks per second, both supporting auto-batching.

Comment: so you mean, we need to implement it at method side, right?    we add a loop to run BlockingQueue.drainTo() to get the the list with queue items, then invoke processor to handle it.

Comment: You could do that.  Both producers and consumers have methods ;)

Comment: I've build a library to handle batching and flushing on fixed timeout: https://github.com/fulmicotone/io.fulmicotone.fqueue

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick attempt at processing objects in batches, using a background thread to collect and process objects pushed onto a queue by other threads:

```
public abstract class Batcher<E> implements Runnable {

    public static interface BatchProcessor<E> {
        public void processBatch(List<E> batch);
    }

    private final BlockingQueue<E> queue;
    private final BatchProcessor<E> processor;

    private Batcher(BlockingQueue<E> queue, BatchProcessor<E> processor) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                List<E> batch = new ArrayList<E>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    batch.add(queue.take());
                }
                processor.processBatch(batch);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

To use this, you create a `BlockingQueue` and put objects on it, create an instance of an implementation of `BatchProcessor` to process the batches, then create an instance of `Batcher` to pump objects from the former to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the API documentation of interface [`java.util.Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), which has several implementations.

There's also a standard API, [Java Message Service (JMS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) to deal with queueing systems for exchanging messages between different processes.

Comment: How does this address the problem of batching? I don't think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is what you need, or possibly [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). That would allow you to setup a synchronization point that will trigger consumers after a certain number of operations have occurred, and you can use a standard queue as the container object.

Comment: can you please provide some code snippet, would be good to understand thought.

Comment: A `CountDownLatch` is particularly useful when you have either several threads producing or several threads consuming (or both). It's not clear that is the case here.